# "Could not connect to server: No such file or directory" While deploying Rails app with beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While deploying an application with `Rails 3.2.17`, we are getting following error.

**eb-commandprocessor.log**

```
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace) (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:189:in `rescue in exec'
    ...
caused by: command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh
```

Here is our `database.yml` configuration

```
 production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Surprisingly we are able to start rails console and we also verified that all above environment variables return correct value.

And also able to connect via psql with following command
`psql -h RDS_HOSTNAME -d RDS_DB_NAME -U RDS_USERNAME`

Comment: I have the same problem here but with Rails 4

Comment: any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Same problem here. Also working when doing it manually. Working on it...

Answer (score 1):

On my side the issue was coming from the fact that I deleted my `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings` and so `RACK_ENV` was not defined, AWS set it by default to `production` which led my application to have the wrong database hostname.

I debugged that by adding `echo` statement in  `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh` to display `RACK_ENV` and noticed it was empty.